# Airflow through two different diameter outlet

Tags: fluid-dynamics

A fixed airflow travels through a duct that would be split into two outlets. One of the outlets has a smaller diameter, which the other has a larger diameter, will the larger diameter outlet has a high airflow rate than the smaller diameter outlet?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

We can not tell exactly that rate of air flows from the two different nozzles be equal. It depends on the speeds of air  coming from them. If we assume them to be equal, then obviously the larger one has high air flow rate.